# How to make my flask application to update the loglevels dynamically

Tags: python, flask, logging, dynamic-programming, python-logging

I want my flask application to update the log levels dynamically.
I have defined loglevel in config.ini file as below

Config.ini

loglevel = 10

Now in setting.py file I have created a constant (loggerlevel) which with the help of configParser class stores the loglevel's value in loggerlevel.

setting.py

```
loggerLevel= int(config.get('default', 'loglevel'))
```

Now this constant is being used in dt_log.py file to create a logger like this

```
dt_log.py

config = ConfigParser() config.read(os.path.join(setting.default_path,'config.ini'))

handler.setFormatter(formatter) logger=logging.getLogger(__name__) logger.setLevel(setting.loggerLevel) 
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Now I'm updating config.ini through api but the problem is all the constant in setting.py file is being assigned their values on running the application and during runtime even if you change the config.ini and update the loggerLevel value in setting.py the log level still won't change.

Please someone suggest something I'm trying to find a way

Tried updating the constant value of setting.py variable via globals()[loggerLevel] = config.get('default', loglevel ')

Tried rewrite the config file.